# Displaying currency signs in UILabel on Xcode

Tags: xcode, unicode, uilabel, currency, urlencode

I am trying to display the gliphs for a currencies by using either the html format or unicode one. By using the former I tried all sorts of operations including: `stringWithUTF8String`, `decodeFromPercentEscapeString`, `CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` but none of them succeded in turning € into a euro sign. With Unicode the issue was slightly better as:

```
NSString *aStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[@"\u20ac" UTF8String]];
```

actually prints a euro sign, but for I reason I do not understand, if I provide the string as the result of a method, the unicode code gets displayed instead.

What is the standard way for displaying euro, dollar or pounds signs in a UILbel?

Answer (score 4):

UILabel automatically resolves unicode strings, no need to decode:

```
label.text = @"\u0024"; // dollar
label.text = @"\u20ac"; // euro
```

Refer to [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/) for the encoding name.

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't if the value comes from a function as it is in my case:

Comment: If any one would interested to print INR Symbol ,  NSString *s=@"\u20B9" NSLog(@"%@",s);

Answer (score 3):

What about directly copying and pasting those characters in your string as :

```
NSString *aStr = @"Euro-€, Dollar-$, Pound-£";
label.text=aStr;
```

Comment: As a matter of fact I take those values from a DB: hoping in your suggestion I tried inserting the euro sign in the DB cell but unfortunately it came out as (null). To answer better the previous suggestion, directly printing the unicode seems to work, but when it comes from a function as in my case it gets displayed instead of the value.

Comment: This is the function I use to get the glyph:
    -(NSString*) glyph{
    NSError * error=nil;
    NSString* urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://miafotoit.serversicuro.it/iPhone/inarrivo/taxi/gliphForCurrencyCode.php?code=%@", currency];
    NSLog(@"%@", urlString);
    NSString* filePath =[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    return filePath;
}

Comment: This the url feeding which either the unicode or the html code comes out:
https://miafotoit.serversicuro.it/iPhone/inarrivo/taxi/gliphForCurrencyCode.php?code=EUR or GBP etc.

Answer (score 2):

I found a very simple solution:

```
float fareValue=/*float value*/;
NSNumber* fareNumber=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fareValue];
NSString* formatted=[NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:fareNumber numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
"\u{00A3}"
```

The '@' is no longer needed